# Как узнать количество подписок в Subscription?

Tags: rxjs

Я добавляю подписчиков в экземпляр `Subscription`. Как узнать сколько подписчиков находится в `subscriptions`?

```
const subscriptions = new Subscription();
...
formKeys.forEach(key => {
subscriptions.add(
    form.controls[key].valueChanges.subscribe(...)
}
```

Comment: `subscriptions['_subscriptions'].length`. Зачем тебе это нужно знать?

Comment: это нужно было для дебага